# Batch file running two vbs scripts for backing up

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a system that's running an old FoxPro program which generates 8 character long DBF files. We make a back up of the program folder each day, but at 5pm the program has generated so many of these garbage dbf's that it's a nuisance. I would just set a del *.dbf in the back up script but there are a few dbf with letters in their name that are needed to run the program.

Files are located in F:\Clean This\

Any numerically titled .dbf files need to be deleted

Any alphabetically titled .dbf file should be left alone

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "F:\Clean This\"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
collide = "ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

For Each objFile in colFiles
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "DBF" Then
        num = 1
        For num = 1 to 26 'find files with names start with # 0-9
            If Left(objFile.Name,1) = Left(collide,num) Then
                Wscript.Echo "Save " & objFile.Name
            Else If int(Left(objFile.Name,1)) > 0 Then
                Wscript.Echo "Delete!"
            End IF
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

As you can tell the If statements can be done better, I'm unsure how to better work it out. The two Wscript.Echo commands are just placeholders because if anything else I can't get find a suitable delete function that would work in a dos environment (I've already tried kill, no).

Suggestions and improvements would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally got it working, and here's what the end result was. It works wonderfully and the higher ups and others were rather impress that it worked better than the built in utility of the program we're backing up. Score!

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "..\System Folder"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set DirFiles = objFolder.Files
Dim oFile
For Each objFile in DirFiles
If "dbf" = LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) Then
    If IsNumeric(objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile.Name)) Then
        objFSO.DeleteFile(objFile)
    End If
End If    
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IsNumeric() to check for file names consisting of digits only:

```
>> For Each sN In Split("abc 123 1O1 101")
>>     If IsNumeric(sN) Then
>>        WScript.Echo "delete", sN
>>     Else
>>        WScript.Echo "keep", sN
>>     End If
>> Next
>>
keep abc
delete 123
keep 1O1
delete 101
```

Your check fails, because you use Left() where you should use Mid():

```
>> collide = "ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
>> num = 5
>> WScript.Echo Left(collide,num)
>> WScript.Echo Mid(collide,num,1)
>>
ABCED
D
```

and even then `Left(objFile.Name,1)` will look at only the first character of the file name.

**Update (wrt comments):**

Apply IsNumeric() to the base name:

```
  Dim oFile
  For Each oFile In goFS.GetFolder("..\testdata\17817161").Files
      WScript.Stdout.Write oFile.Name
      If "dbf" = LCase(goFS.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) Then
         If IsNumeric(goFS.GetBaseName(oFile.Name)) Then
            WScript.Stdout.WriteLine " delete"
         Else
            WScript.Stdout.WriteLine " keep"
         End If
      Else
         WScript.Stdout.WriteLine " ignore"
      End If
  Next
```

output:

```
123.dbf delete
123.txt ignore
abc.dbf keep
```

Comment: I've tried IsNumeric(), but as there's a .dbf extension it errors. Num was placed in the move to the next letter in the array, not print out n number of letters. Also delete brings up a mismatch error :/

Comment: Just realized I didn't have a collide called as an array in the if statement, my apologies.

Comment: Line 2 Char 1, Error: Object required 'goFS' Code 800A1A8 Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Comment: So what? Just use your own FSO.

Comment: What would be a good deletion method? Kill and Delete won't work for me for some reason.

Comment: I got it, I got it! Thank you so much for your help! :D